# Reverse analysis of an Elf file

Tags: elf

question：

CrackMe1 is an **ELF executable** that can be executed independently in Android.

Execute CrackMe1 program in shell and prompt "Input Your Answer"

Input the correct string, press enter, if the program output "True Answer", it means yes, output "Wrong Answer", it means failure

**What I need to do is reverse analyze the ELF file and find the correct string to be entered (which can be understood as password here).**

I use IDA to decompile but find no string matching information in the decompiled result

[Here is the code of the decompiled main function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQQPc.png)

I would like to ask what method can be used to find the string to be entered for the above situation.

It can be a tutorial or a specific example

file： https://pan.baidu.com/s/1Tfbtk792UgYLj9XxUmb8yg?pwd=49ff
passwd：49ff

Comment: I think you should ask a more specific question.  Just saying "what should I do" sounds like "please complete my homework exercise for me".  Also, "how can I get started" questions are not usually a good fit here.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions (it doesn't really matter whether this is actually your homework or not, it's a homework-type problem and the same issues apply).  Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308745/are-how-would-i-get-started-questions-too-broad

Comment: Thank you. This is my first time to ask a question. Some of the things I said are not appropriate.
I will revise my question as soon as possible